# How can I share text or content to facebook using JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, share, next.js13

I've developed a website featuring various posts, each equipped with share buttons for different social media platforms, including Facebook. However, I'm facing an issue with the Facebook Link Sharer API. Currently, I can only share the URL, and I'm eager to enhance the sharing functionality to include the post text as well.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to achieve text sharing using the Facebook Link Sharer API. If so, could someone guide me on how to implement this? Any insights, code snippets, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible. The user has to type the post text. You can only influence title, description and thumbnail of the shared URL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.